# executeSql throws results as errors

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I don't understand why the following code works like this: all the results goes to the catch blocks. The last catch block after "select * from danceMoves" will actually write "swag" to the console.

This is a simple project created using ionic start and then adding cordova-sqlite-storage. Following the Ionic site document.

```
public testSQLite() {
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('create table if not exists danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))')
      .then(() => { debugger; console.error('Executed SQL') })
      .catch(e => { debugger; console.error(e) })
      .then(() => { debugger; return db.executeSql("insert into danceMoves(name) values('swag')") })
      .then(() => { debugger; return db.executeSql("select * from danceMoves") })
      .then(result => { debugger; console.log(result.rows.item(0).name) })
      .catch(error => { debugger; console.error(error) })
      .then(() => { debugger; return db.executeSql("select * from danceMoves") })
      .then(result => { debugger; console.log(result.rows.item(0).name) })
      .catch(result => { debugger; console.log(result.rows.item(0).name)});
  })
  .catch(e => { debugger; console.error(e) });
}
```

Comment: I just recently stumbled over the same issue. Have you found any cause or solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found a possible solution (at least it fixed the problem for me).
`executeSql` method expects two parameters: a statement and a params array.

The statement may contain parameters (e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?`), which are resolved using the objects given in the params array (e.g. `[1]`).

The params array parameter is marked as optional, since may work without parameters. However, if the array was not given, the result set of the query would be thrown as an error instead of returning it. To fix this I always specified an empty array as the second parameter, which solved the issue for me.

Example call:
`db.executeSql(SELECT * FROM danceMoves, []).then(result => console.log(result.rows.item(0).name)`

Comment: Seems in later versions they changed it so that the parameter array is not optional to avoid confusion.